# It seems that 1 of my sessions are not even saving throughout pages

Tags: php, session, fopen, save, undefined-behavior

This is where the code begins to fail (fun.php):
It also seems that the text file isn't being written to, it doesn't even create the file

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == False)
    {
        header("Location: /login.php");
        return ;
    }
    include ('/home/manseld/public_html/scripts/config.php');

    if(($_SESSION['Banned'] == True && (!file_exists("/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/". $_SESSION['CurrentUser'] .".txt"))))
    {
        $_SESSION['Banned'] = False;
    }

    if(file_exists("/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/". $_SESSION['CurrentUser'] .".txt"))
    {
        header("Location: /error.php?e=banned&img=fuuu");
        return ;
    }
// Log User(s) IP 

    if(($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == True) && (!$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] == "ManselD"))
    {
        ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $user = $_SESSION['CurrentUser'];
        $txt = date("h:i") ." | ". $user ." | ". $ip ."\n";
        $url = "accounts/logs/". trim(date(F) ."-". date(d) ."-". date(Y) .".txt");
        $file = fopen($url, "a");
        fwrite($file, $txt);
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

Now, this is where `$_SESSION['CurrentUser'];` Is set (In login.php) Or in this case, not set >.>

```
session_start();
$user = stripslashes($_POST['user']);
$pass = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
$banned = "/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/$user.txt";
$normal = "/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/$user.txt";
$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] = "$user";

if($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == True){
header("Location: /fun.php");
return;
}else{
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = False;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// Banned Users
if(($_SESSION['Banned'] == True && (!file_exists("/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/".$_SESSION['CurrentUser'].".txt")))){
$_SESSION['Banned'] = False;
}
if(file_exists("/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/".$_SESSION['CurrentUser'].".txt")){
$_SESSION['Banned'] = True;
header("Location: /error.php?e=banned&img=fuuu");
return;
}else{
$_SESSION['Banned'] = False;
}
```

I don't really think that it should be happening, it's pretty odd.
Any ideas?

Comment: Explain more about problem. do you get any errors? what you expect and what you get?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop each script. (*Always* when something doesn't work.)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Banned in /home/manseld/public_html/fun.php on line 10. Which is the line: if(($_SESSION['Banned'] == True && (!file_exists("/home/manseld/public_html/accounts/banned/".$_SESSION['CurrentUser'].".txt")))){
But now i fixed it (will edit main post)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question (which session variable doesn't work?) but

`$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] = "$user";`

should be

`$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] = $user;`

Comment: The quotes are redundant, but equivalent.

Comment: Ok, i did that. 
File still isn't being written to. But the CurrentUser is now being saved. :)